# Xamarin.Forms shared preferences

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

The followig code is written in the Shared Project.

```cs
// importing Packages

    using Android.Content;
    using Android.Preferences;

// storing the values as SharedPreferences


    ISharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.GetSharedPreferences("UserInfo", FileCreationMode.Private);
    ISharedPreferencesEditor edit = pref.Edit();
    edit.PutString("Username", username.Text.Trim());
    edit.PutString("Password", password.Text.Trim());
    edit.Apply();        


// retrieving the values

    ISharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.GetSharedPreferences("UserInfo", FileCreationMode.Private);
    string userName = pref.GetString("Username", String.Empty);
    string password = pref.GetString("Password", String.Empty);
```

When running the code we get that following error:

```
'Android.Preferences.PreferenceManager' does not contain a definition for 'GetSharedPreferences'
```

What's the correct way to use `SharedPreferences` in Xamarin.Forms ?

Comment: Also you could use my cross platform settings plugin via NuGet https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Plugins/tree/master/Settings

Comment: james have you any sample code for xamarin forms in android.?

Comment: For the library, it is all documented. I do have a sample; https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Plugins. it is straight. Forward and adds the code for you.

Comment: james, their are so many plugins but i want to use Shared preference so which one i have to use?

Comment: My settings plugin uses shared preferences if you read my github.

Comment: can we stored the data for whole the application life cycle.? If user Close the application and return back to the application at that time values are still stored into it.@JamesMontemagno

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ISharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences(this); 
ISharedPreferencesEditor editor = prefs.Edit();
editor.PutString("username", name);
editor.PutString("password", password);
editor.Apply();
```